# count with setters an geters in a method

Tags: jsf

I want to add +1 every time a method runs, and then show it in an outputText, but this just add another 0 beside the existing one every time the method runs, what can I do to fix this?

BEAN

```
private int count=0;

//constuctor

public void doSomething(String asnwer){

 count++;
... 
}
//setters and getters
```

JSF page

```
<p:panelGrid id="ver">
            <h:outputText value="#{bean.count}"/> //getter for the count
</p:panelGrid>

<p:commandButton value="Japan" action="#{bean.doSomething(japan)}" update="ver" />
```

Comment: Try aspect oriented programming to implement this. You don't want this kind of logic mixed into your business logic.

Comment: What you have posted is not a bean. It is just a variable and a method, not a bean. So post a complete bean implementation with the corresponding annotation.

Comment: ujulu...It is called "Abstraction", as a programer you should know it.

Comment: As a programmer you should know that the information you provided is not enough to define a jsf bean :-)

Comment: Im just a music teacher trying to make apps for my students....its sessionScoped by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Making the count variable static can solve your problem.

Comment: if I make the count static,  I can reach it in the commandButton